# SQLAlchemy filter with many-to-many relations

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

A *store* can have many interests. User request a product that is *tagged*. Query required is to get the *product requests* that have tags **shared** with current store.

```
# in Store -> relationship('Tag', secondary=store_interest_tags, lazy='dynamic', backref=backref('store', lazy=True))
store_tags = store.interests 
matched_requests_to_store = [] 
for tag in store_tags:
    r = session.query(ProductRequest).filter(ProductRequest.product_tags.contains(tag)).all()
    matched_requests_to_store.extend(r)
```

I am sure there might be a more efficient way to query that. I have tried the following:

```
session.query(ProductRequest).filter(ProductRequest.product_tags.any(store_tags)).all()
```

But got

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: subquery must return only one column
LINE 5: ..._id AND tag.id = product_requests_tags.tag_id AND (SELECT ta...
```

Any idea how to achieve such query?

Answer (score 0):

A query like this might work, I think it could be done with less joins but this is less rigid than dropping into using the secondary tables directly and specifying the individual joins:

```py
q = session.query(
    ProductRequest
).join(
    ProductRequest.tags
).join(
    Tag.stores
).filter(
    Store.id == store.id)

product_requests_for_store = q.all()
```

With a schema like this:

```py
stores_tags_t = Table(
    "stores_tags",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("store_id", Integer, ForeignKey("stores.id")),
    Column("tag_id", Integer, ForeignKey("tags.id")),
)

product_requests_tags_t = Table(
    "product_request_tags",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("product_request_id", Integer, ForeignKey("product_requests.id")),
    Column("tag_id", Integer, ForeignKey("tags.id")),
)

class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = "stores"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(), unique=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=stores_tags_t, backref=backref('stores'))

class ProductRequest(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product_requests"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(), unique=True, index=True)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=product_requests_tags_t, backref=backref('product_requests'))

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tags"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your implementation! After some tries, I guess I found the solution. Can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```py
session.query(ProductRequest).filter( ProductRequest.product_tags.any(Tag.id.in_(store_tag.id for store_tag in store_tags) ) ).all()
```

Comment: I think this will work.  It helps a lot if you print out the SQL that is generated before running the query so you can verify it is doing what you expect.  Ie. printing the query before to add `.all()`.  This might slow down if the store tags grow to be very long but it should work.